# in python, is it possible to write a while loop and all its contents on one line?

Tags: python

I ask because I am trying to mess with a irc bot in my friends channel, and can't for the life of me get it to work

basically the bot is phenny which has a python interpreter and I am trying to get it to print out the string "linux open source linux open source" 100 times

```
x = 9000; while x >1: x = x - 1; print "linux"
```

and

```
x=9000; while x>0: print 'linux'; x = x-1 .
```

are what I have tried so far, and I am not sure how I would get this all on one line.

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: I would have to guess 2.7 since the bot itself was written 5 years ago

Comment: I understand the downvote, and I really agree with the python forced indentation as it makes the code beautiful, but my current requirement is something that fits conveniently on one line since the python code is evaluated on only one line.

Comment: I think the down votes are more about the question really being 'how do I spam IRC?'

Comment: well the thing is the bot itself is kind of a nuisance, and the creator knows and acknowledges it, so I am using its programming against it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `exec` you can do whatever you want in one line, this is very dangerous and extremely hacky though (never do this in real code!), however it actually answers your question, which is *"write a **while** loop and all its contents on one line?"*

```
exec"x=10\nwhile x>0: print x; x-= 1"
```

Comment: thats a very interesting solution, had no idea about exec. thank you for the help, the other answers were great, but this answer expanded my knowledge

Answer (score 5):

```
for i in range(0, 100): print "linux open source"
```

Comment: The `0` there is redundant.

Comment: not the question, but then again the question isn't appropriate to this site

Answer (score 4):

```
for j in range(100): print 'linux';
```

Answer (score 1):

As you know, python is an interpreter language. The codes should be written line by line. While loop needs 5 whitespaces after the condition. Ie, each instructions and codes inside the loop should have atleast 5 whitespaces infront of them. The codes should be written line by line. Your code wont work, since you are out of the rules.